# Filter JSON Data In Custom Formatter

Tags: javascript, json, tabulator

I am fairly certain that this is possible with Tabulator, however my JS knowledge is very limited.

I would like to filter the JSON data parsed to my table, so it can be summed together, providing a "calculation based" column. My data looks as follows:

```js
{'id': '1' ,'date': "3/20" ,'type': 'API2' ,'volume': 14000 ,'price': 119000,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '2' ,'date': "3/20" ,'type': 'API2' ,'volume': 500 ,'price': 119000,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '3' ,'date': "4/20" ,'type': 'API2' ,'volume': 9000 ,'price': 129000,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '4' ,'date': "3/20" ,'type': 'API4' ,'volume': 50000 ,'price': 119000 ,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '5' ,'date': "3/20" ,'type': 'API4' ,'volume': 1000 ,'price': 109000 ,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '6' ,'date': "4/20" ,'type': 'API4' ,'volume': 13000 ,'price': 119000 ,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
{'id': '7' ,'date': "3/20" ,'type': 'API6' ,'volume': 14000 ,'price': 119000 ,'color': '#FFFFFF'},
```

My columns (which are obviously incomplete) would look like:

```js
{
    id: '1', 
    title: 'Volume',
    formatter: function(cell){
        //Requires Help
    },
    editor: '', headerTooltip: '', align: 'center', sorter: '', script_name: '', 
    script_parameter: '', headerFilter: '', headerFilterPlaceholder: '', 
    headerSort: false, frozen: false, resizable: false, minWidth: 35, 
    editorParams: {values:[]}
}
```

An example of how I would like this column to operate would be summing all of the volume values of all records which meet a particular criteria, perhaps type is 'API2', or date is '3/20' and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a column of sums is all that desirable, I think what you would want is a row of sums at the top/bottom of the table.
Either way, I will provide both ways for you to see.

https://jsfiddle.net/s60qL1hw/ - Contains all examples below.

**Creating a column of sums.**

You need to first get the table data and then you need to create your filter/sum based on that.

Here is an example formatter that creates a sum of the volumes where the type is 'API2'.

```
    formatter: function(cell) {
      const tableData = cell.getTable().getData();
      let mySum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++){
        if (tableData[i].type === 'API2'){
            mySum += tableData[i].volume;
        }
      }
      return mySum;
    }
```

**Tabulator column calcs**

Use the bottomCalc or topCalc option in your column definition.  This is for the volume column.

```
  {
    title: "Volume",
    field: 'volume',
    bottomCalc: 'sum'
  }
```

You can also use custom functions for the calculation. (I don't use the calcParams here, but you can see how those are used in the documentation.)

```
    bottomCalc: function (values, data, calcParams){
      let mySum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if (data[i].type === 'API2'){
            mySum += values[i];
        }
      }
      return mySum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a column based off of a calculation of the value of other columns then you need to look at using a [Mutator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/mutators#mutators)

if we assume you have a third column that you want to hold a value of the sum of the ***val1*** and ***val2*** columns then the definition would be something like this:

```js
var sumMutator= function(value, data, type, params, component){
    //value - original value of the cell
    //data - the data for the row
    //type - the type of mutation occurring  (data|edit)
    //params - the mutatorParams object from the column definition
    //component - when the "type" argument is "edit", this contains the cell component for the edited cell, otherwise it is the column component for the column

    return data.val1 + data.val2;
}

{title:"Sum Column", field:"sumcol", mutator:sumMutator}
```

If you are manipulating the data, you should always use a ***mutator*** as it changes the data itself, which means that the column will sort correctly. if you use a ***formatter*** that is purely a visual effect and will mean you would be unable to sort or filter the column.